# Use ScrollView instead of ListView with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

### What I want to achieve

I'm currently working with the library [React Native Touch Through View](https://github.com/rome2rio/react-native-touch-through-view) in order to build a scroll-up view which allows for content behind it to be interacted with.

### Current state

Got it working well for ListView as in the demo, but struggling to get it working with a ScrollView instead.

This is my current code:

[image: Current code]

This is what happens when I run it:
(the ScrollView container gets pushed down below TouchThroughView).

[image: Demo of current state]

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Whats wrong with `ListView` ?

Comment: @SGhaleb I am going to put a mix of different content in there - the text is just for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Use style `position: 'absolute'` in both components, and set their width and height to the screen's `({ height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'));`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Filipe! Sadly that just pushes them both on top of each other: https://imgur.com/a/9SDPIxL